# How to get rid of "[podname] not installed..." warning?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I (for the life of me) cannot get rid of this warning.

[image]

Basically, I originally had the pod *SwiftLint* installed, but I eventually decided to remove it. To do this, I thought simply removing the line `'pod SwiftLint'` from my Podfile, then performing the Terminal command `git install` would do the trick. Well it did...mostly...except lo and behold, this warning appeared.

Now, I've tried everything I can possibly think of to get rid of this warning, but I have been unsuccessful. Does anybody know how to get rid of this??

Things I've tried:

- Deintegrated Cocoapods and then re-added only the pods I wanted (I.e. NOT SwiftLint).
- Deleted the project's DerivedData folder
- Reinstalled SwiftLint and then deleted it again with the command `pod install --no-repo-update`
- Other things which I can't remember

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you were installing SwiftLint, you probably followed the instructions in the "[Xcode](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint#xcode)" section of their README, to add a build phase that runs this script:

```sh
if which swiftlint >/dev/null; then
  swiftlint
else
  echo "warning: SwiftLint not installed, download from https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint"
fi
```

This script tries to run `swiftlint` whenever you build the project, and if `swiftlint` is not found, it outputs the warning that you see.

If you are not using SwiftLint anymore, you can just remove this build phase:

[image]

Comment: My project was originally pulled from someone else's GitHub repo so I wasn't even aware a script like this existed. Again, many thanks.